# dllexport in headers confusion

Tags: dll, linker

I'm confused as to why `__declspec(dllexport)` or equivalent needs to go in the header file. Say I'm writing a library. Surely the users don't need to know or worry about whether symbols are exported or not, all they care about is that the function declarations are there and will presumably be linked against the shared or static library itself. So why can't all this boilerplate go into source files, for use only at build time?

The only use case I think of is a situation where someone is writing a wrapper of my library and needs to export all of my functions as well, but in general that is not the case - is it really worth the hassle of having all the export stuff inside public headers? Is there something I'm missing, is this a technical limitation of linkers..?

I'm asking because I like my headers and build system to be clean, and as `dllexport` stuff is generally set/not set based on whether we are **building the library** as a shared or static library, I find it strange that it should end up inside public headers since it's (to my understanding) fundamentally a build time concept. So can someone please enlighten me on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure I can provide a great answer.  My impression is that it serves several purposes:

1. It speeds the loading of DLLs, particularly when lots of DLLs are used (because there are fewer exported symbols to search through)
2. It reduces the possibility of symbols colliding at run-time (because there are fewer exported symbols)
3. It allows the linker to complain about undefined symbols (instead of just assuming it might find them at run time.

I'm sure there are other reasons.  I generally wrap my APIs in something like this:

```
#if defined(MY_LIB_CREATION)
    #define MY_LIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define MY_LIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

And then all of my API functions & classes are defined as MY_LIB_API:

```
class MY_LIB_API Foo {};
MY_LIB_API void bar();
```

And then in the project file defined MY_LIB_CREATION for the project implementing your library.